# prevent input[type=number] from automatically rounding off floating point values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to prevent floating point values from being rounded off when used as values for input[type=number]. I cannot use any other type as per requirement.

For example, I cannot bind an input[type=number] with value "3.00", it is automatically rounded off to "3".

I am trying to bind values using angularjs.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('controller1', ['$scope', function ($scope){
  $scope.value=3.00;
}]);

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller1">
  <input type="number" ng-model="value" /><br/>
  {{value}}<br/>
</div>
```

this is the link to the PEN : http://codepen.io/cyrilpanicker/pen/aqucJ?editors=101

Comment: Make it a string then parse the string if you ever need to perform calculations on it.

Comment: u mean remove the type="number" attribute? can't do that coz type="number" is a requirement..

Comment: Sorry, that would probably be very undesirable.  But yes, you'd have to take off `type="number"`...unless you brought in hefty amounts of jquery..

Comment: if `type = number` is a requirement, and you want to use float values, then some more information is needed, as `type=number` is specifically meant to only use integer values.

Comment: If you really want to support, it on input (on display anyways you could use filter, if it is editable field then it is probably not needed to show 3.00 as 3.00) you may want to reformat it after ngModel is done. It is the ngModel evaluation that is rounding it off. I have posted an answer, possibly that might work.

Comment: @Cyril Any luck with the answer(s) below?

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the ngModel rounds off the value after it is parsed. One workaround could be to handle it using a custom directive with lower priority (`-1`) than `ngModel` (which runs at priority `0`) so that it runs after ngModel has parsed. And in the directive register a formatter which will use number filter to reformat the input's modelvalue.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value=3.00;
}).directive('formatNum', function(numberFilter){
  return {
    priority:-1, //<-- Important
    require:'ngModel',
    link:function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel){
        ngModel.$formatters.push(format); //Push a formatter
        function format(){
          return numberFilter(ngModel.$modelValue , 2); //Round off to 2 dec
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller= "MainCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="value" format-num/><br/>
  {{value | number:2}}<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Use this if you really really want to have the editable field have that trivial `.00`. Probably it is not really worth doing that at all, for readonly fields you can anyways use number filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) filter to format the number when you display it. {{value | number:2}} will always show it with 2dp:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller1">
  <input type="number" ng-model="value" /><br/>
  {{value | number:2}}<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wants the formatting on the input's value not on the display.